# Solution Folders and Toolbox Items incompatible?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2005

In Visual Studio 2005, I've recently reorganized a solution with over 30 projects into 5 solution folders. However, since I've done that, all the custom controls and user controls from my assemblies have disappeared from the WinForms Toolbox.

Has anyone experienced this? Are there workarounds? Is this fixed in Visual 2008? I've tried to reset the toolbox, but it still does not populate the toolbox properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fortunately fixed in VS2008. The project that contains your control can be placed in solution folders, and their controls will still appear in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the tool box to add custom assemblies and namespaces. Perhaps the assemblies your tool box was referencing moved after you re-structured your project?

Comment: I could probably do that to make it work, but it's a hassle, because these are controls from assemblies within that solution. I didn't have to do this before. It automatically populated all the controls discovered within the solution's projects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you built the Solution since you reorganized it?  When you build a control it is fast added to the toolbox.  When you remove the output of the build (like by doing a clean), it is removed.  BTW, the fast add does not use any ToolboxItem class/attributes.  So don't expect the icons to be right, etc.